# MySQL - selecting data where count is more than 1

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| keyword                             | landing_page                                                   |
+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| orange                              | https://www.example.co.uk/                               |
| apple                               | https://www.example.co.uk/                               |
| pear                                | https://www.example.co.uk/                               |
| apple                               | https://www.example.co.uk/                               |
| apple                               | https://www.example.co.uk/landing-page |
+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to select any keyword which has more than one distinct landing page, so in this example, we'd return:

```
apple, https://www.example.co.uk
apple, https://www.example.co.uk/landing-page
```

How can I achieve this with MySQL?

**UPDATE**:
I tried the following but it didn't seem to work:

```
select keyword, count(landing_page) 
from search_data 
group by keyword 
having count(distinct landing_page) > 1;
```

Comment: Don't count distinct in your HAVING clause

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Why not?

Comment: @Barmar, Why not DISTINCT in your select * to cut down on the amount of data to filter? If you distinct in your having clause the data could have already been filtered before this point

Comment: Please show output of `CREATE TABLE`, as indexing seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

The query you tried is part of the solution. Use that query as an inline view, to identify the keywords that have more than one landing page.  Join result from that query back to the original table.

```
SELECT t.keyword
     , t.landing_page
 FROM ( -- keyword with more than one landing page 
        SELECT r.keyword
          FROM search_data r 
         GROUP BY r.keyword
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.landing_page) > 1
      ) s
 JOIN search_data t
   ON t.keyword = s.keyword
GROUP BY t.keyword, t.landing_page
ORDER BY t.keyword, t.landing_page
```

This isn't the only approach. There are other query patterns that will also return an equivalent result. As an example of another approach, using a correlated subquery to check for the existence of another row in the table with the same keyword but a different landing_page:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.keyword, t.landing_page
  FROM search_data t
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM search_data r
                 WHERE r.keyword = t.keyword
                   AND NOT ( r.landing_page <=> t.landing_page )
              )
 ORDER BY t.keyword, t.landing_page
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Demonstration setup:

```
CREATE TABLE search_data (keyword VARCHAR(10), landing_page VARCHAR(80))
;
CREATE INDEX search_data_IX1 ON search_data (keyword, landing_page)
;
INSERT INTO search_data (keyword, landing_page) VALUES
 ('orange','https://www.example.co.uk/')
,('apple','https://www.example.co.uk/')
,('pear','https://www.example.co.uk/')
,('apple','https://www.example.co.uk/')
,('apple','https://www.example.co.uk/landing-page')
;
```

EXPLAIN Query 1

```
EXPLAIN    
SELECT t.keyword
     , t.landing_page
 FROM ( -- keyword with more than one landing page 
        SELECT r.keyword
          FROM search_data r 
         GROUP BY r.keyword
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.landing_page) > 1
      ) s
 JOIN search_data t
   ON t.keyword = s.keyword
GROUP BY t.keyword, t.landing_page
ORDER BY t.keyword, t.landing_page

--     id  select_type  table       type    possible_keys    key              key_len  ref       rows  Extra
-- ------  -----------  ----------  ------  ---------------  ---------------  -------  ------  ------  ------------------------
--      1  PRIMARY      <derived2>  system  (NULL)           (NULL)           (NULL)   (NULL)       1  
--      1  PRIMARY      t           ref     search_data_IX1  search_data_IX1  13       const        2  Using where; Using index
--      2  DERIVED      r           index   (NULL)           search_data_IX1  96       (NULL)       5  Using index
```

Execute Query 1

```
SELECT t.keyword
     , t.landing_page
 FROM ( -- keyword with more than one landing page 
        SELECT r.keyword
          FROM search_data r 
         GROUP BY r.keyword
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.landing_page) > 1
      ) s
 JOIN search_data t
   ON t.keyword = s.keyword
GROUP BY t.keyword, t.landing_page
ORDER BY t.keyword, t.landing_page

-- keyword  landing_page
-- -------  --------------------------------------
-- apple    https://www.example.co.uk/
-- apple    https://www.example.co.uk/landing-page
```

Explain Query 2

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT DISTINCT t.keyword, t.landing_page
  FROM search_data t
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM search_data r
                 WHERE r.keyword = t.keyword
                   AND NOT ( r.landing_page <=> t.landing_page )
              )
 ORDER BY t.keyword, t.landing_page

--     id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys    key              key_len  ref               rows  Extra
-- ------  ------------------  ------  ------  ---------------  ---------------  -------  --------------  ------  -------------------------------------
--      1  PRIMARY             t       range   (NULL)           search_data_IX1  96       (NULL)               6  Using where; Using index for group-by
--      2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  r       ref     search_data_IX1  search_data_IX1  13       test.t.keyword       1  Using where; Using index
```

Execute Query 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.keyword, t.landing_page
  FROM search_data t
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM search_data r
                 WHERE r.keyword = t.keyword
                   AND NOT ( r.landing_page <=> t.landing_page )
              )
 ORDER BY t.keyword, t.landing_page

-- keyword  landing_page
-- -------  --------------------------------------
-- apple    https://www.example.co.uk/
-- apple    https://www.example.co.uk/landing-page
```

Comment: Both queries just seem to hang

Comment: If the queries "hang", that suggests that these tables have a large number of rows and/or MySQL is not making effective use of indexes, and/or a suitable index is not available. For diagnosing performance, I would start with the EXPLAIN to see the execution plan. We'd expect MySQL to make effective use of an index `ON search_data (keyword,landing_page)`.  Ideally, MySQL would be "Using index" and not "Using filesort" for the operation required for GROUP BY. If the tables are very large, we probably want to add WHERE clauses to limit the number of rows.